# Use the same drawable for 2 different SDK versions

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources, android-drawable

I am trying to add support for the new Material UI in my apps, but I have encountered an annoying situation.

Before SDK 14 the black app menu needed white icons. Starting with SDK 14 the Holo light theme needed dark icons. Now when migrating to Material I need white icons once again. So basically I have a folder drawable-hdpi-v11, one drawable-hdpi-v14 and one drawable-hdpi-v21. drawable-hdpi-v11 and drawable-hdpi-v21 have the same images and of course Lint warns me that I have the same resources duplicated.

I have look into aliases [Creating alias resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources), but it doesn't seem to offer the functionality I need. Do you know any way to obtain the same result (white images for SDK<14 or SDK>=21, dark for SDK>=14 and SDK<21) without duplicating the resources?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html Note: it's only **guidelines**. You decide what foreground color fits best with your background.

Comment: Are you talking about action bar icons? If so, there's always the Light.DarkActionBar themes if you want to always use white icons on a dark background.

Comment: Why don't you think that the aliases will work?

Comment: @Funkystein: I know they are only guidelines, but consistency is what I am looking for.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Yes I am talking about the action bar. For the Material theme I am indeed using DarkActionBar, that is why I need to use white icons. However Holo theme has a white action bar hence the need for black icons on pre-KitKat.

Comment: So why not 'Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`? Or better yet, [AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) for a consistent look everywhere.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have tried adding the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_heart" />` into an xml in drawable-hdpi-v21 for example and added the white image in the default drawable-hdpi folder. However I still get the image from drawable-hdpi-v14.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Using AppCompat is my backup option. I am targeting for consistency with the OS, that is why I am trying to make the app blend as much as possible with the OS.

Comment: Of course, if every other app uses AppCompat (for example, every Google app that comes with the device and is available on the Play Store), then you're app will still look out of place. Seems like the effort you're putting into this would be better spent on app functionality.

Comment: @Adrian-CostinȚundrea: "into an xml in drawable-hdpi-v21" -- what is the file named? "However I still get the image from drawable-hdpi-v14" -- when asking for what resource?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have named it icon.xml... I have tried naming it ic_action_heart.xml, but I get a runtime error. And yes... I am getting the dark icon instead of the one from the default folder (white).

Comment: @Adrian-CostinȚundrea: To use an alias with `@drawable/icon`, try having  the dark `icon.png` in `res/drawable-hdpi-v14/` and `icon.xml` in both `res/drawable-hdpi-v21/` and `res/drawable-hdpi/`, where `icon.xml` points to an `ic_action_heart` located in `res/drawable-hdpi/`. It is unclear from your comments if that is your setup or not.

Comment: My configuration is as follows: `res/drawable-hdpi/ic_action_heart.png` (white), `res/drawable-hdpi-v11/ic_action_heart.xml`, `res/drawable-hdpi-v14/ic_action_heart.png` (dark), `res/drawable-hdpi-v21/ic_action_heart.xml`.With this configuration I get the following error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi-v21/ic_action_heart.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02001d`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Added my configuration above...

Comment: @Adrian-CostinȚundrea: Your error refers to `xxhdpi`. Is your `hdpi` setup mirrored to `xxhdpi` (i.e., same mix of resources in the `xxhdpi` directories)? I'm also hazy on what `ic_action_heart.xml` is pointing to in its `<bitmap>` element; it cannot be `ic_action_heart`, as that would be recursive.

Comment: @CommonsWare: You are correct... the configuration is mirrored for xxhdpi also. But following your suggestion I hvae found the issue. If I rename the default one ic_action_heart_white.png and point the xml to it... it works. So I guess this question has been answer. How can I mark you reponse as answered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `@drawable/ic_action_heart` to resolve to:

- white on < 14
- dark on >= 14 and < 21
- white on >= 21

In that case:

- Have a dark version of the icon as `ic_action_heart.png` in `res/drawable-hdpi-v14/`
- Have a light version of the icon as `ic_action_heart_white.png` in `res/drawable-hdpi/`
- Have a drawable alias, named `ic_action_heart.xml`, in `res/drawable-hdpi-v21/`, pointing to `@drawable/ic_action_heart_white`
- Have a drawable alias, named `ic_action_heart.xml`, in `res/drawable-hdpi/`, pointing to `@drawable/ic_action_heart_white`

And, of course, you would have the same basic structure in other density buckets (e.g., `-xxhdpi`). Since density is more important than is API level, I think you will need to have density-specific versions of the aliases.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning that after implementing the aliases for 4 icons the resulting APK is actually 2 KB larger then the one with duplicated resources.

Comment: @Adrian-CostinȚundrea: That behavior may well depend upon the sizes of the resources themselves -- icons are usually pretty small files. The benefit, though, is more of DRY, so you don't have to maintain duplicate copies of the icons.

Comment: The total size of duplicates for all the resolutions would be around 15KB. So I guess compressing the resources actually saves more data then the overhead of the linking. But DRY is still DRY and, as they say, a build with no warnings is a happy build :). A nice case study thought.